# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mern

Trying to Post request in react using form but server is responding to 500 error.
The handlesubmit function looks like this, its not working always shows an internal server error with 500 code.

```
async function handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    SetBtnText("Sending...");
    const response  = await fetch("http://localhost/form/contact",
    {
        mode: 'no-cors',
        method :"POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        FormData
    })
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data));

    SetBtnText("Send");
    let result = await response.json();
    SetFormData(InitialFormData);
    if (result.code === 200){
        setStatus({ success: true, message: 'Message sent successfully' });
    } else{
        setStatus({ success: false, message: 'Something went wrong, please try again later.' });
    }
}
```

The Server.js looks like this..

```
const express =  require('express')
const cors = require("cors");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const router = express.Router();

const dotenv = require('dotenv')
dotenv.config({path:"./.env"})

const app = express();
app.use('/form', router);
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.listen(80 , ()=>{console.log("Server Running at Port:80")})

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
      user: process.env.EMAIL,
      pass: process.env.PASSWORD
    }
})

router.post('/contact',(req, res)=>{
    const Name = req.body.FirstName + req.body.LastName;
    const Email = req.body.Email;
    const Message = req.body.Message;
    const Phone = req.body.Phone;

    const MailOptions = {
        from : Email,
        to :process.env.EMAIL,
        subject: "Contact Form Submission - Portfolio",
        html : `<p>Name: ${Name}</p>
            <p>Email: ${Email}</p>
            <p>Phone: ${Phone}</p>
            <p>Message: ${Message}</p>`,
    }
    console.log(MailOptions)

    transporter.sendMail(MailOptions, function(error){
        if (error) {
          res.json(error)
        } else {
            res.json({code:200 , msg : "Sent Successfully"})
        }
      });
});
```

What should I do to make this work. Please suggest how do I remove this internal server error

Answer (score 0):

From your code I can see you are missing the server port in the react side
it should be `http://localhost:80/form/contact` NOT `http://localhost/form/contact` also on the server you are already using cors no need to set `no-cors` on the client the code will work
for a little tip
use [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) to always test your APIs before integrating it on the client side that way you can be sure the problem is not from the server and if it is fix it before trying it out on the client side

Comment: Shows the same error again. And without mode: 'no-cors', one more error occurs that restrictred due to cors policy...